# RecyclerView is reloading every time firebase realtime database data set

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to set value to child in firebase realtime database after item clicked in recyclerview

Recyclerview is reloading everytime after setting value to child in Firebase realtime database

I use custom adapter for the recyclerview

How can I fix this...

**CODE**

```
public class date_adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<date_adapter.MyViewHolder> {

Context context;
private ArrayList<date_model> list;
int times;
private choosing_model model;
private ArrayList<date_model> doneItemsAre;
private ArrayList<date_model> dateModels;

date_adapter(Context context, ArrayList<date_model> list, choosing_model model, ArrayList<date_model> date_models) {
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
    this.model = model;
    this.dateModels = date_models;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.date_view_item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.month.setText(list.get(position).getMonth());
    holder.date.setText(String.valueOf(list.get(position).getDate()));

    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    doneItemsAre = new ArrayList<>();

    if (model.isDone()){
        if ((dateModels.get(position).isChecked())) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("user").child(user.getUid()).child("challenges").child("challenge").child(model.getChoosingTitle()).child("oneWeek").child(String.valueOf(position)).child("checked");
            holder.calendarCard.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#03ADFF"));
            holder.month.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            holder.date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
            reference.setValue(true);

        }
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView month, date;
    CardView calendarCard;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        month = itemView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_month);
        date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_date);
        calendarCard = itemView.findViewById(R.id.calendar_card);
    }
}
```

}

This is my code for setting value

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#read_once_using_a_listener

Comment: please post your question with your code sample you will get faster response

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be updating a value in the database when the `onBindViewHolder` is called (`reference.setValue(true)`), so each time the item is rendered. You should probably only do that update only once, or only when the user performs an action on the data.